# How did Busujima Eiji figure that it was about boobs?

Tags: senryuu-shoujo

[image: senryuu-shoujo]

On the third koma on "As Is" chapter, Nanako wrote,

> Eighty and a five
>     Prolly about fifty five
>     Eighty plus a two

How did Eiji figure that it was about the president's breast size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This relates to how clothing manufacturers measure [the bust, waist, and hip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bust/waist/hip_measurements) of women, also known as a woman's "three sizes".  From this, Nanako is basically reading off [what she thinks are] the club president's sizes are.

Comment: Also, the first koma where the club president said "*How about we try describing **this scene** the way it is in words?*" and her reaction on the fourth koma are the obvious hint. Eiji described the scene outside the window, Nanako described the club president...